# Angular drop-down-list for 20k records

Tags: angular, dropdown

I have to show 20k records in a drop-down list in my application.

I have search criterias to find drop-down records by `ID` and `Name`.

What will be the best way to implement this kind of scenario?

Comment: Use Autocomplete instead.

Comment: will it be affect on application performance ?

Comment: Autocomplete loads the request when needed. so, on load time NO but when someone typing-in then it depends on your data and response.

Comment: suppose in search I'm typing last records available in DB in that case will it be affect on performance ? Thanks for your quick replay

Comment: That based on your backend approaches. If the proper index is built then it will not affect the performance.

Comment: Thank and lot for valuable suggestion @Rohit.007

Answer (score 0):

you may use pagination or use virtual dropdown items where you only render the visible li's in the scroll viewport

this code may help you:

```
isElementInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pdfContainer = this.element.nativeElement;

    const windowHeight = (pdfContainer.innerHeight || window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    const windowWidth = (pdfContainer.innerWidth || window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);

    const vertInView = (rect.top <= windowHeight) && ((rect.top  rect.height) >= 0);
    const horInView = (rect.left <= windowWidth) && ((rect.left  rect.width) >= 0);

    return (vertInView && horInView);
}
```